# Is there a new HTML5 way to move between rows of inputs in a table using the arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a table filled with text input fields (input type=text). I have written some javascript code which catches the up and down arrow keys and detects if the active element is in a table, and if so it moves the active element up or down.  This works fine under (for example) Firefox.

Today I was testing CSS on a different page (with no javascript) on the default browser that comes with android and I discovered that this feature already exists on that browser without the need for any javascript.  So immediately now I wonder if there is something new in HTML5 that would allow me to achieve this functionality without using any javascript.  No luck finding anything so far.  Is this just something that the Android default browser implemented that is out in left field?

Comment: Please add code if any.Use http://jsfiddle.net/ if you want

Comment: Ok, here is basically what my [test HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/qxeeL/) looks like.  It's just a simple javascript table,  using HTML5.  On Firefox hitting the up and down arrows does nothing.  On my phone using the stock Android browser (which reports itself as an unknown version of Mozilla on Linux) the down arrow moves to the next field below and the up arrow to the next field above.  Obviously, if this is some feature that is enabled by default in this browser but which I can turn on with a switch on other browsers I would rather not include unneeded javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is unique to the Android browser. It's not part of HTML5, nor any other browser I'm familiar with.